# Issue with creating JSON output for Busted lua unit testing

Tags: json, unit-testing, lua, lua-busted

So I have some simple unit tests setup in busted.  I am a little new to LUA, so I may be missing something obvious.

When I run:

```
lua test.lua
```

I get expected results (7 succeed, 1 failed on purpose to try out busted) in the nice terminal output.

My ultimate goal however is to output JSON results, and have a script that consumes JSON from multiple tests to make some summary pages for my fellow WoW addon developers.

When I run:

```
lua test.lua -o json
```

my terminal pauses for a brief second, and I am returned to the command line.

There is no terminal output, nor is any file created.

I am relatively new to lua and busted in general, could you provide me any pointers?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

And here is a link to [Busted's website](http://olivinelabs.com/busted/).

Comment: Apparently, latest Busted version fails producing JSON output of **some** tests with error code 1. Must try digging deeper...

Comment: Also, could You please clarify Lua and Busted versions You're using?

Comment: Does `lua -o json test.lua` work by any chance?

Comment: @Kamiccolo

LUA version - 5.1.5
Busted version - 2.0.rc10-0

Comment: @EtanReisner That gives me a lua error as it doesn't recognize the -o option.  I tried 

`busted -o json test.lua`.  

It ran, but produced no output just like my original post.

Comment: Ah, true, I had originally been thinking you were running `busted` directly but then realized you were using `lua` without rethinking my argument order question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in question was caused by `dkjson` module not using functions in tables properly. The bug  was fixed in [pull request #449](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/busted/pull/449), so, You should wait for the fix to get to next release candidate (>2.0.rc10-0) of `Busted` or just download and build recent version from [here](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/busted). Btw, relevant bug report - [#448](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/busted/issues/448).